# Why is AU Lab not saving my output device settings?

Tags: macos, audio, soundflower

I use the combination of Soundflowerbed and AU Lab on my MacBook Air in order to have a system-wide equalizer.

**In AU Lab**, when I open a document I previously created, **the device selected in the output settings is not restored correctly**. I saved the document with the "Built-in output" output device, but when I re-open the document, the output device is set to "Soundflowerbed (2ch)". So I have to manually reselect the right output device each time I open my document.

How can that setting be saved/restored correctly?

Answer (score 1):

In AU Lab, go to Preferences > Document, and untick the "Use preferred audio device when opening documents". The next time you'll open AU Lab, it will keep the "Built-in audio output" as output device!